# How to expand a table row from multiple parent columns. More than just one column

Tags: antd, react-component

The react-component table api accepts a property called `expandIconColumnIndex={number}` which when used with the property `expandIconAsCell=false` allows you to specify an **individual column** to render the expand icon into.

Is there a way to specify **multiple columns** to render the expand icon into?

Something like

```
expandIconColumnIndexes={[0,1,3]}
```

Comment: Where do you see `expandIconColumnIndex`? https://ant.design/components/table/

Comment: Here https://github.com/react-component/table
It's not included in the antd documentation but instead on the react-component table repo api